# How can I use the ModelViewProjection Matrix to get from screen space to object space?

Tags: opengl, matrix

So I have this Square that I render each frame. Not a cube, 2 triangles. 
I draw this Square passing a modelviewprojection (P * V * M) Matrix to a shader. 
The projection Matrix can be either a perspective projection or an orthogonal projection. 
I've been trying passing screen coordinates in, bringing them to clip space, and then multiplying with the inverse MVP Matrix, but I'm just not getting the results. 
Basically I need to figure out the the cursor is contained within the Square.

Here's my code thus far:

```
Matrix4 inverse = myMVP;
inverse.invert();

Vector2 clippos((aGlobalPos.x / width) * 2 - 1.0f, ((1.0f - (aGlobalPos.y / height)) * 2) - 1.0f);
Vector4 wspace = inverse * Vector4(clippos.x, clippos.y, 0, 1);
wspace.x /= wspace.w;
wspace.y /= wspace.w;
return Vector2(wspace.x, wspace.y);
```

I'm expecting that if the return value is in the range of `0 -> squareSize` it will be contained.

Could someone take the time to explain what I'm doing wrong, and why?

Thanks

Comment: Applying the inverse MVP matrix to your screen position will result in a 3D vector, but you only use the `x` and `y` coordinates. Why? Also note that, since you don't have depth information from the mouse cursor, this transformation will only give you a direction vector in object space, not a single position. It will describe a ray emanating from the camera position into the direction your cursor points.

Comment: Because the origin of the Square is the corner, and the vector is in object space, i figure I only need to check the X and Y values, because Z in object (the normal of the square) is irrelevant. I may be wrong though.

Comment: Again: the result of this operation won't be a point in object space; it will be a vector which points from the camera position into the view direction. So you'll need to compute the camera position transformed into object space and then intersect the ray (camera->viewdir) with your object.

Comment: Maybe this is just nitpicking, but: strictly speaking, the result of this operation will be a point in object space. It is just the unprojection of (x,y,0,1) in clip sapce. This of course in no especially meaningful point in the general case. So I agree with @cfh: Either construct a ray (bei either transforming the camera position into object space, or by unprojecting two points with different z coordinates) and intersect it, or try to get the clip space z value for your point of interest (e.g. by reading window space z from the depth buffer and undoing the depth range transformation).